# RxJS - Infinite scroll - sending requests while previous not arrived

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm very new to reactive programming, this is my first thing with RxJs, an infinite scrolling:

```
public pageByScroll$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, "scroll")
  .map(() => document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.scrollTop - document.documentElement.clientHeight)
  .filter(x => x < 800)
  .debounceTime(200)
  .scan(count => count + 1, 0);


handleScroll() {
  this.pageByScroll$.subscribe(
    pageToLoad => this.advertiserService
      .getAdvertisersByPage(pageToLoad)
      .subscribe(advertisers => this.advertisers = this.advertisers.concat(advertisers))
  );
};

getAdvertisersByPage(page: number): Observable<AdvertiserClass[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.advertisersUrl + '/pager/' + page)
     .map(res => {
       return res.json().map(advertiser => {
         return new AdvertiserClass(advertiser);
       });
     });
 }
```

My problem is comes from test db server is far away, and its need 1+sec to receive the data.
If i keep scrolling while the new data is not received and the pages height is small, it keeps sending request for the next page.
How could i make it to wait sending requests while the previous is not received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many subscribes.  Compose your event streams to create one observable. Assuming, pageByScroll$ works as intended, you can use [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) to append Observable streams together (last one completes before next one begins, emitted in order).

```
var o= this.pageByScroll$.concatMap(t=>this.getAdvertisersByPage(t));
o.subscribe(t=> this.advertisers.concat(t));
```

Comment: Thank you, your first part solved the problem :) With the second version i had some problem, but i want to do it that way. My code looks like this now: `constructor() {
    this.newFetchedAdvertisers = this.pageByScroll$.concatMap(t => this.advertiserService.getAdvertisersByPage(t));
    this.advertisers = this.advertisers.concat(this.newFetchedAdvertisers);
  }         
  advertisers: Observable<AdvertiserClass[]> = this.advertiserService.getAdvertisersByPage(0);
` But the new fetched advertisers overwrites the actual advertisers, not concatenate the two observables.

Comment: Now in the consturcor i have this: `this.newFetchedAdvertisers = this.pageByScroll$.concatMap(t => this.advertiserService.getAdvertisersByPage(t));
    this.advertisers = Observable.merge(this.advertisers, this.newFetchedAdvertisers);`
And keeps overwriting the advertisers, not 'pushing' new ones to older ones. I have no idea why that's not working :/

Comment: If you keep advertisers as an array (not as an observable) doesn’t it work? Mergemap will merge out-of-sequence, not likely what u want

Comment: Yes, it's working as an array :) Just tried the second way too, keep as observable all way long and was frustrating i can't make it :)

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. And the second way won't work because it overwrites the bound observable result every time the scroll event fires.

Answer (score 2):

Nice pageByScroll function.

As @pixelbits says, the basic problem is `this.pageByScroll$.subscribe()` should be `this.pageByScroll$.map()`, but playing around with it I notice it also pages on scroll-up.

You might solve that by remembering the scrollTop last seen.
Note this also works if you scroll down, up, down.

```js
const pageByScroll$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, "scroll")
  .map(() => document.documentElement.scrollTop)
  .scan((scrollTop, last) => scrollTop > last ? scrollTop : last, 0)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map(downwardScrollTop => 
    document.documentElement.scrollHeight
       - downwardScrollTop
       - document.documentElement.clientHeight
    )
  .filter(x => x < 800)
  .debounceTime(200)
  .scan(count => count + 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping make a better function :)